# How to create an anime eye

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, workflow

So i'm learning how to sculpt using this 3d model as a reference:
https://www.artstation.com/artwork/3YZ9Y

I have the basic shape of the head, now i want to create the eyes for this character.
I think the shape is a cylinder , but i don't know how to create the eye itself.

So i tried using the knife project tool on a cylinder, but i don't get the same results.

For me the shape is a cylinder because it doesn't look like a sphere.

So how i can create the eye?

[image: my attempt using the Knife project tool]

[image: what i try to achieve]

Comment: its just a really large sphere. Cylinder is too flat from side view.

Comment: another question i have if he is using a mirror modifier, or if it's a sphere for both eyes?
Also how does he bend the circle of the eye?

Comment: cut sphere for both eyes. Mirror modifier simply copies the split sphere(or whatever) from 1 side to the other. bend circle of the eye?

Comment: So he is using two spheres one for each eye right?

What i mean about the bending is that the circle that he use to texture the eyes (iris, pupil, etc) follow the shape of the sphere, i don't know how to create that circle.

https://imgur.com/MH2eFkK

Comment: yeah, pretty much. They are split though because if the whole sphere for the eye was visible, it would show through the head because its very large. You can split a duplicate of the sphere and scale down for the iris.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a sphere and a [lattice modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html).

- Add a sphere for the eye.
- Add a lattice object.
- Select the eye and then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the lattice.
- Parent the eye to the lattice <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and choose Lattice Deform.
- In Edit mode for the lattice, move its points on the axis you want the eye to shrink.

Now as you rotate the eye, it will stay deformed within the lattice.

[image: anime eye]

Answer (score 0):

In this video shows a technique very good for manga eyes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsk9IKLHN7Y

using an independent object for the iris and just an empty white space for the cornea. The problem i had with the lattice modifier is that is harder to keep the iris consistent specially when the character is looking at the left of the right.